# Is the source code for this app from the documentation available for download?

Tags: android

In the multi-pane layouts documentation for Android there are examples of different app.

I'm interested in reproducing the look of this app, and would like to know how they created the labels above field values (i.e. "Phone" with the blue underline), and also other theme effects (the arrow pointing to the list item).

This looks like the native contact manager for Android, but I'm unable to find the source code. I've looked in the SDK under samples, but it doesn't appear to be there (or I don't know what it's called).

Is this app one of the Android samples?

[image]

Comment: You're asking several questions here. Break it down into parts that can be answered.

Comment: @MikeW - there's really only one question, it's in the title, and it has a simple factual (but unknown) answer.  The rest is basically just justification of what the poster would like to learn from it if it is available, though it might elicit some "consolation prize" results if no one knows a positive answer to the title question.

Comment: @MikeW first off, Android is open source and while I have the SDK. I also downloaded the source for the SDK. The above is the standard contact manager found on most devices, but the source code does not appear part of the SDK. Seems logical to assume this is open source as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default "People" app is open source as well and you should be able to find all the code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts) on Github.

Comment: cool, they also have the default Camera app and Calendar app there too!

Comment: "It's OpenSource baby!" - PearlJam feat. Android :)